# Ubuntu iptables allow certian IP addresses

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04, ip-address

I have a riak cluster that I need to only allow certain IP addresses access to the information.  I am currently using, `-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.200 -j ACCEPT`, to allow this IP address and at the bottom of my rules I have `-A INPUT -j REJECT` and `-A FORWARD -j REJECT`, to reject other traffic.  Can anyone advise where I am going wrong? Thanks!

The full rules:

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.181 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8098 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8099 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4369 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5678:5679 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 2500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 2):

Netfilter has 5 main Chains. You can ignore PREROUTING and POSTROUTING for now, so the 3 you need to manipulate are INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT.

INPUT and OUTPUT control the traffic directed to the system itself, while FORWARD controls the traffic that *passes through* and is directed to another machine (the case of a gateway).

In your case, if you want to allow external users to connect to the system itself, you need the following set of rules:

```
# Rule 1: accept packets from established connections to enter and leave the system
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Rule 2: accept new connections entering the system
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -s 192.168.10.200 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 



# Rule 3: block all connections entering and leaving the system (if not previously accepted)
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP

# note: only use the filtering on output if you want to control outgoing connection
# if you want to let all connections leave your system, just comment this out
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j DROP
```

Rules 1 and 3 are general, Rule 2 is connection specific. Just use that sample and add new Rule 2 when you need new connections.

If you want something more solid, take a look at this: http://1nw.eu/!MJ

Comment: I'm not sure my question was too clear...the iptable rules i have in place now still allows all ip address connections.  How do I only allow certain ip addresses to access my server information with iptables?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: the set of rules I put above blocks all incoming and outgoing connections unless explicitely listed, which is what you are asking for. What do you call your 'server information' ?

Comment: I am working on a riak node, and I currently can access a "buckets" information via the browser, which I am trying to prevent access from all ip addresses but what i specify.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: so use my ruleset above and add as many "rule 2" as you need, specifying the source IP everytime.

Comment: I have used the rules you provides and it is still allowing all ip address access via the browser...not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: launch the following commands and post the result in your question above (not as a comment here): "iptables -t filter -L -v -n" and "iptables-save"

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to allow the incoming traffic using: `-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.200`, or forwarded traffic using: `-A INPUT -s 192.168.10.200`. You are missing the related traffic. You need to add:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

`INPUT` should be used for traffic destined to the firewall itself. `FORWARD` should be used for traffic destined to other machines. Also, make sure to enable IP forwarding in this case.

Comment: I have -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT in my table but it is still not working.

Comment: -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.181 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8098 -j ACCEPT
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8099 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4369 -j ACCEPT

-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5678:5679 -j ACCEPT 

-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 2500 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

Comment: Above is a copy of my iptalbe rules

Comment: You can edit your question instead of adding more comments!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've read your complete rules.

One important thing first: Please **don't** mix -A with -I.

- `-A` **appends** rules to the end of the chain
- `-I` **inserts** rules into the chain (if the position is not specified, it's inserted in the **first place**)

So, your iptables rules are actually:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5678:5679 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4369 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8099 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8098 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.181 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 2500 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

As you can see, the INPUT rules #1 through #4 **does not** limit any source address.

Now if you really want to limit access to those ports to 192.168.1.181, you'll have to do it like this:

```
# Established connections should just pass
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Loopbacks will not match 192.168.1.181, so we ACCEPT them here
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
# Other than 192.168.1.181, we reject
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.181 -j in_allow
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT
# Allow only the following ports
-A in_allow -p tcp --dport 5678:5679 -j ACCEPT
-A in_allow -p tcp --dport 4369 -j ACCEPT
-A in_allow -p tcp --dport 8099 -j ACCEPT
-A in_allow -p tcp --dport 8098 -j ACCEPT
-A in_allow -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 2500 -j ACCEPT
-A in_allow -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
#
-A FORWARD -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

Only one question: why the `-m state --state NEW` for `--dport 2500`?

**Important note:** Don't forget to first FLUSH and ERASE the whole iptables rules before applying the above.